# After few days my LoadBalancer External IP doesn't Work

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

When I deploy my Application my  loadBalancer works just fine.But after few days, my loadBalancer External IP just doesn't work.My pod is running just fine and there is no issue with the logs as well.
I have had this issue with two different Application multiple times now.Not able to debug what's the issue.Have someone faced this type of error before?

Comment: What type of external IP address?

Comment: What do you mean external IP doesn't work? oO

Comment: I am not able to connect to the external IP which is of type LoadBalancer

Comment: So I found out the issue..There is nothing wrong with the LoadBalancer.It was my GCP that requires certain firewall setting for one to access something running on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

For troubleshoot, you can check endpoints of your LoadBalancer service.
You need to see your pod's ip addresses and forwarded ports according your service like below.

```
$ kubectl get ep nginx
NAME    ENDPOINTS        AGE
nginx   100.96.5.44:80   17s
```

And describe

```
$ kubectl describe ep nginx
```

Then check logs of affected pod.

```
$ kubectl get pods
$ kubectl logs -f <pod-name>
```

ExternalIP addresses created to forward traffic to internal backends(pods)

If there is something, please provide your Yaml files, and outputs.